# MKMapView viewForAnnotation, saving an annotation

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

From my understanding, when you do something like:

```
[self.mapView addAnnotation:anAddress];
```

It adds an annotation to the map and then looks at the delegate method for the view like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *placeMarkIdentifier = @"SimplePinIdentifier";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[AddressAnnotation class]]) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[theMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:placeMarkIdentifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:placeMarkIdentifier];
        }
        else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        NSLog(@"my annotation: %@", [annotation description]);
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.tag = ANNOTATION_VIEW_TAG;

        UIButton *detailDisclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailDisclosureButton;

        [self performSelector:@selector(showCallout:) withObject:annotation afterDelay:0.5];

        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I am using the example in More iOS 5 Development and just customize my call out with my own AddressAnnotation  object.  So this part works as I expect.

When the disclosure is pressed, the user can save the location (it just adds it to an array).  That works.  So when I reload the map, it'll add back that annotation.

The part that I do not understand is, if after I save the first pin to the map, I then drag the pin somewhere else on screen.  Then I save it again and my array has two objects.  The current mapView only has one pin since I dragged the first pin from its original location.  When I try to reload the map, it only has one pin at the last location I dragged it to.  It does not have two pins as I would expect.  I basically just do:

```
[self.mapView addAnnotations:_locations]; // where _locations is an array that stores my saved <MKAnnotation> objects
```

When I NSLog the _locations, I see two objects.  I would think that it would then add two pins to the map since the delegate gets called and would add a pin to the screen for each object in the array.  However when I NSLog in the delegate viewForAnnotation:, it only gets called once, for the object that I last dragged, not the original pin.

What's going on here?  Thanks!

Edited:

Code where I save off a location:

```
- (void)mapPickerDidSelectMap:(Map *)aMap {
    DataManager *dmgr = [DataManager sharedInstance];
    if (![dmgr locationExists:self.address forMap:aMap]) {
        NSMutableArray *oldLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:aMap.locations];
        [oldLocations addObject:self.address];
        aMap.locations = oldLocations;        
    }
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [dmgr.maps enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"obj: %@", [obj description]);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Please provide the codes on saving the locations and create another annotation. I think the two objects maybe the same. Have you NSLog the two object to check if it is the same?

Comment: I added the code where I save the location.  I believe the two objects are different since when I log the output after I save off the locations, the memory addresses are different.

Comment: I can't see the code you have added. btw. the location coordinate is different right?

Comment: Sorry I didn't click Save Edits yet.  I thought I did :P

Comment: Yes I logged the location coordinate and it is in fact different.

Comment: Is the first annotation's coordinate outside the current map view?

Comment: @lu yuan No they are in the same map view.

Comment: So it's really odd, as you said "viewForAnnotation:, it only gets called once"